# 10 pixels of transparent space beside my drop down links

Tags: css

I am currently working on my nav bar. One issue I am having is that when I added 10px of padding to my main navigation `.navi ul`, 10px of clear space got added to all the drop down items under each menu item and I just can't figure out why. You can see this in action here: http://cbchaverhill.onedirectionconnection.com/

Here is my CSS:

```
.navi {
    background: #222; /* Show a solid color for older browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#252525, #0a0a0a);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#252525, #0a0a0a);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#252525), to(#0a0a0a)); /* older webkit syntax */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#252525, #0a0a0a);
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto 6px;
    width: 100%;
}

.navi ul {
    font-size: 13px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 0 0 -0.8125em;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.navi li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

.navi a {
    color: #eee;
    display: block;
    line-height: 3.333em;
    padding: 0 1.2125em;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.navi ul ul {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    display: none;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 3.333em;
    left: 0;
    width: 188px;
    z-index: 99999;
}

.navi ul ul ul {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}

.navi ul ul a {
    background: #f9f9f9;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #ddd; color: #444;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    width: 188px;
}

.navi li:hover > a,
.navi ul ul :hover > a,
.navi a:focus {
    background: #efefef;
}

.navi li:hover > a,
.navi a:focus {
    background: #f9f9f9; /* Show a solid color for older browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#f9f9f9, #e5e5e5);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#f9f9f9, #e5e5e5);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#f9f9f9), to(#e5e5e5)); /* Older webkit syntax */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f9f9f9, #e5e5e5);
    color: #373737;
}

.navi ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

.navi
.current-menu-item > a,
.navi .current-menu-ancestor > a,
.navi .current_page_item > a,
.navi .current_page_ancestor > a {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The css you apply to the `.navi ul` also applies to the nested `ul`'s.

```
.navi ul {
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

One way to resolve this:

```
.navi ul ul {
    padding-left: 0px;
}
```

Or:

```
.navi ul {
    font-size: 13px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

Comment: I'll check your anser as soon as the time limit ends!

Comment: @Noelle My pleasure, I added a second option as I was unsure how deep the nesting of ul's would do.